# How to interpret the parameters in a DIMM datasheet?

Tags: memory, ddr, dram

I am trying to understand the internal layout of my DDR4 DIMM. Such as:

- rank number
- bank number
- row/column of the memory array within a bank

According to intel customer script, the reported DIMM parameters are like this:
[image]

From this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1210400/what-does-32gb8gbx4dr-mean-in-the-dumped-ram-info) I know that:

- DR = Dual Rank
- x4 means the DRAM chip has a physical channel of 4-bit width (**please correct me if I am wrong about this.**)

Then I searched for the part number `M393A4K40BB1-CRC` and found the [Samsung Production Selection Guide](http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungsemiconductor/pdfs/PSG_1H_2016.pdf). It says this for this part number:

[image]

And I found the [datasheet](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global/file/product/2017/02/DDR4_8Gb_B_die_Registered_DIMM_Rev1_8_Oct_16-0.pdf). It says this:
[image]

So it basically says the DDR4 module `M393A4K40BB1-CRC` is made of DDR4 SDRAM component `K4A8G045WB-BC##`. And as I checked the pyhsical DIMM, it is indeed that componnet.  **But I simply cannot find this `K4A8G045WB-BC##` component in the previous componnet table.** I think this is a doc error.

But anyway, what I really care about is how to derive the *bank*, *row*, *column* info from this sheet?

And how to interpret below parameters from the datasheet?

From the Component table:

- 1G x 8

From the Module table:

- 4G x 72
- 8Gb(2Gx4)*36

It seems `x` and `*` have different meanings. What's the difference?

### ADD 1

According to the book [Memory Systems by Bruce Jacob](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123797519).

[image]

So it seems the `x4` `x8` represents the **device width**, which means how many `arrays` an independent bank contains. An **array** can contribute a **single** bit when specifying a `row` and a `column`. A **bank** can contain multiple arrays so that it can contribute **multiple** bits when specifying a `row` and a `column`.

The calculation is like this for the first row:

> Capacity = 1 rank x 16 devices/rank x 4 banks/device x 4 arrays/bank x
>   4K rows x 1K cols = 1024Mb = 128MB

Explanation for the 1st row, **from the lowest level (array) to the highest level (memory module)**:

1. Each **array** contains `4096 * 1024 = 4M bits`  (Number of Rows and Columns)
2. Each **bank** contains `x4` arrays, that is `4M * 4 = 16M bits`  (Device Width)
3. Each **device** contains `4` banks, that is `16M * 4 = 64M bits` (Number of Banks)
4. Each **Rank** contains `16` devices, that is `64M * 16 = 1024M bits` (Devices per Rank)
5. Each **SDRAM memory module** contains 1 rank, that is `1024M * 1 = 1024M bits = 128M Bytes`

> Device Density = 4 banks/device x 4 arrays/bank x 4K rows x 1K cols = 64Mb

**Device Density** refers to the bullet 3 above.

### ADD 2

A quote from the above book:

> ...a x4 DRAM (pronounced “by four”) indicates that the DRAM has at
>   least four memory arrays and that a column width is 4 bits (each
>   column read or write transmits 4 bits of data). In a x4 DRAM part,
>   four arrays each read 1 data bit in unison, and the part sends out 4
>   bits of data each time the memory controller makes a column read
>   request.

Below diagram clearly illustrates how the **column width** and **bank numbers** are related **logically**.

[image]

> Note that each of the DRAM illustrations in Figure 7.4 represents
>   **multiple arrays but a single bank**. Each **set** of memory arrays that
>   operates **independently** of other sets is referred to as a bank, **not an
>   array.**

And:

> A system is composed of potentially many independent **DIMMs**. Each DIMM
>   may contain one or more independent **ranks**. Each rank is a set of DRAM
>   **devices** that operate in unison, and internally each of these DRAM
>   devices implements one or more independent **banks**. Finally, each bank
>   is composed of slaved memory **arrays**, where **the number of arrays is
>   equal to the data width of the DRAM part (i.e., a x4 part has four
>   slaved arrays per bank).**

[image]

***When it comes to the memory jargons, there are so many confusion...***

Comment: You may be interested in my answer to similar question. It also has video https://superuser.com/questions/1288686/what-is-dimm-depth-width/1404619#1404619 . It also has link to Carnegie Mellon lecture about DRAM geometry

Comment: @user996142 Yes it does help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

My current understanding:

- **8Gb(2Gx4)*36**

  According to [here](https://technick.net/guides/hardware/umg/04_003/):

> The expression "8M x 8" describes one kind of 64Mbit chip in more
>   detail. In the memory industry, DRAM chip densities are often
>   described by their cell organi-zation. The first number in the
>   expression indicates the depth of the chip (in locations) and the
>   second number indicates the width of the chip (in bits). If you
>   multiply the depth by the width, you get the density of the chip.

So the whole expression means 36 DRAM **device/chips** make up a DIMM (32 for storage and 4 for ECC). Each DRAM device/chip's *density* is 2Gx4 = 8Gb. `2G` means the total *locations*. `x4` means each bank in the device/chip has 4 arrays, which contributes 4bits for a *location*. The geometry details such as row, column and bank are not recoverable from this description.

- **1G x 8**

  This means the DRAM device 1G locations with each location contribute 8 bits.
- **4G x 72**

  This describes the DRAM *module* instead of single DRAM *device/chip*. But in a similar way. The `4G` is the module depth in location count. And each location contributes 72 bits (I think 8bits are for ECC). So the module capacity is 4Gx64 bits = 32GB.

So the take away is: `location count * location size = total size`. This formula is used for both `device density` and `module capacity` notation.

Comment: 2GBx4 means 4 2GB modules. Nothing to do with the current subject.

Comment: I agree, you cannot determine the number of columns, rows or banks given the density of the chips only, even knowing it has x4 arrays per bank.

Comment: For M321RYGA0BB0-CQK by Samsung, it has spec of Density = 96 GB with Component Composition = (4G x 4) x 40. It seems that it does not match any calculation method, what is the reason for this? (Link: https://semiconductor.samsung.com/dram/module/rdimm/m321ryga0bb0-cqk/)

Answer (score -1):

The x4s and x8s refer to the number of banks on the memory component or chip. This number (not the one of individual memory chips on a PCB) gives the Rank of the memory module. So if a module has chips on both sides of the PCB (making it dual-sided), it can still be Single Ranked, Dual Ranked (like in your case), or Quad Ranked, depending on how those chips are engineered.

A Rank (which means a data block) is currently 64 or 72 bits. A module made from x4 chips will need 18 chips for one Single Rank (18 x 4 = 72, 72/72 = 1). This is the ***18** in the table.

A module made from eighteen (*18) x8 chips would be Dual Ranked (18 x 8 = 144, 144/72 = 2).

Since yours has x4 and is DR, it will need ***36** chips of the **x4** type for it to be **DR**. (36 x 4 / 72).

Identically, A module that has 36 x8 chips becomes Quad Ranked (36 x 8 = 288, 288/72 = 4).

So basically, the xN is the number of banks, the *NN is the number of chips.

Comment: From your second paragraph, it looks to me the `x4` or `x8` parts are more like the bit width of a single SDRAM device that is part of a rank. Why do you say it refer to the number of banks? Please correct me if didn't get your point.

Comment: According to the book <Memoy Systems by Bruce Jacob>: `the word bank is only used to denote a set of
independent memory arrays inside a DRAM device`.

Comment: Based on my ADD 2, the x4 doesn't mean the banks number. It means the DRAM array numbers in a single bank. A single bank can have multiple arrays. And these arrays work in unision.

Comment: It does not matter how you call them, the examples and calculations above are clear and valid. Do not confuse the name with other types of Banks. Look at the numbers, not the names.

Comment: xN is not the number of banks, it is the number of arrays per banks (which is even different from the prefetch architecture). Words do matter, otherwise concepts are misinterpreted, and it can be very confusing, because indeed, the above calculation by @Overmind are valid and correct.