# What is DIMM depth/width?

Tags: memory

What is DIMM depth/width?

I think that "(DRAM width) × (the number of DRAMs) = (DIMM width)".
I don't know I am right.

[image]

In case of the DIMM1 above, what's the values of DIMM depth and width??

Comment: I figured it out here: https://superuser.com/questions/1213920/how-to-interpret-the-parameters-in-a-dimm-datasheet. Especially the `ADD 1` part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRAM and DIMM geometry is complex subject, it is better to watch video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLCy3pG7Rc0&list=PL5PHm2jkkXmidJOd59REog9jDnPDTG6IJ&index=26&t=0s

I will try to explain it, though.

**DRAM chip and its banks**

At the lowest level there is a bank: matrix of bits.
You can send row address to this bank, and bank reads row 
and stores it in buffer (also called sense amp).
Row is wide, but interface of bank is narrow: only 8 bits in this case.

You then send column number, and banks sets appropriate part of row 
to the interface.

```
Col0: you have 0-7 bits.
Col1: you have 8-16 bits
```

Meanwhile, row is finished, and you move to the next row.

You can think about bank as about storage of many 8-bit width "words".
Each block has column and row number.

Your DRAM chip has 64Meg (1024 * 1024 * 64 = 67108864) words, 8 bit each.

8 bit is your **DRAM width**. 64Meg is **depth**.
Product is called **density** or capacity.

Think about your DRAM as about home of 67108864 "words" 8 bit each.

So, your chip has 64Megx8=512Mbits capacity (or *density*)

To make everything even more complex, chip may have many banks.
It is still 8 bit width (because all banks have same width) but to
address "word" you need bank number, column number and row number.

It could be that your DRAM chip has 2 banks 32Meg depth each.
Or 8 banks 8Meg each. I do not know, your spec does not tell me that.
Some specs provide number of banks or number of bits in col/row address.

**DIMM module: series of DRAM chips**

DIMM module consists of several DRAM chips.

You can think about it as about huge DRAM chip which is always 64 bit width.
That is because DRAM controller (part of CPU actually) has 64 bit data bus width.
That means it reads 64 bits at one time.

DIMM has 8 chips on one side "emulating" 64-bit long chip.
And it has 8 chips on the other side.
Each side is called rank and could be operated sepately:
DRAM controller "enables" (by setting chip select) first rank, reads data, 
then enables second rank and so on.

Some DIMMs have one rank, but your has two.

**DIMM density** (capacity) is 512Mbits*16 (because we have 16 chips, 512Mb each)
8Gbits or 1GByte (1024MBytes).

Now, think about DIMM as about 64bit width DRAM.
How many 64bit "words" do you have?

You have 128Meg of them. This is your **DIMM depth**

An illustration:
https://www.archive.ece.cmu.edu/~ece740/f11/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:lectures:onur-740-fall11-lecture25-mainmemory.pdf

Answer (score 2):

#### In case of the DIMM1 above, what's the values of DIMM depth and width?

Depth = 16 (The Memory Depth is the total memory capacity in bits divided by the non-parity memory width, ie 1024 / 64)

Width = 64 (The Memory Width specifies the data width of the memory module interface in bits. )

---

#### What is DIMM depth/width?

**Memory Geometry Notation**

Various methods of specifying memory geometry can be encountered, giving different types of information.

**Module**

(Memory Depth) x (Memory Width)

The Memory Width specifies the data width of the memory module interface in bits. For example, 64 would indicate a 64-bit data width, as is found on non-ECC DIMMs common in SDR and DDR1-4 families of RAM. A memory of width of 72 would indicate an ECC module, with 8 extra bits in the data width for the error correcting code syndrome. (The ECC syndrome allows for single bit errors to be corrected). The Memory Depth is the total memory capacity in bits divided by the non-parity memory width. Sometimes the memory depth is indicated in units of Meg (220), as in 32×64 or 64×64, indicating 32 Mi depth and 64 Mi depth, respectively.

**Chip**

(Memory Density)

This is the total memory capacity of the chip. Example: 128 Mib.

(Memory Depth) × (Memory Width)

Memory Depth is the Memory Density divided by Memory Width. Example: for a memory chip with 128 Mib capacity and 8 bit wide data bus, it can be specified as: 16 Meg × 8. Sometimes the "Mi" is dropped, as in 16×8.

(Memory Depth per bank) × (Memory Width) × (Number of Banks)

Example: a chip with the same capacity and memory width as above but constructed with 4 banks would be specified as 4 Mi x 8 x 4.

Source [Memory geometry - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_geometry)

---

#### Further Reading

- [4.3. CALCULATING THE CAPACITY OF A MODULE · Technick.net](https://technick.net/guides/hardware/umg/04_003/)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But I think they are DRAM's width and depth. My reference says DIMM depth is 128Mb and DIMM width is x64.(I changed the picture.)
I thought DIMM width is "x128" because DRAM width(x64) × 16(the number of DRAMs). But It's different from my reference.

Comment: user172497 , if you prefer the answer from your reference, then please make an answer quoting the reference, preferably with a link.

Comment: @user172497 See updated answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill that last link really helps!