# What does (4G x 4) x 40 DRAM Composition mean?

Tags: memory, ddr, dram, sdram

I found two different specifications of memory modules on Samsung's official website, with the same Component Composition but different capacities. **What do the three numbers in Component Composition represent?**

> [M321RYGA0BB0-CQK](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/dram/module/rdimm/m321ryga0bb0-cqk/), Density = 96 GB, Component Composition = (4G x 4) x 40
>
> [M321R8GA0BB0-CQK](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/dram/module/rdimm/m321r8ga0bb0-cqk/), Density = 64 GB, Component Composition = (4G x 4) x 40

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1213920/how-to-interpret-the-parameters-in-a-dimm-datasheet), it mean 40 chips with 4G location and 4-bit width, but it does not meet with the total capacity.